# 2nd order derivative - chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm facing this problem:
let $g(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$ and $f(x,y)=2x^3y-y^2x+x+2y$. Compute $g''(0)$ knowing that $x(0)=y(0)=x'(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $x''(0)=y''(0)=-1$.
I proceeded by computing the first derivative of $g(t)$ with the chain rule, that is
$g'(t)=f_{x}(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+f_{y}(x(t),y(t))y'(t)=(6x^2y-y^2+1)x'(t)+(2x^3-2xy+2)y'(t)$ and by substituting the given value this expression is equal to zero.
So i don't need to compute the second order derivative.
Is it correct or am i missing something?
Thanks a lot in adance for your answers.

Comment: Derive and then substitute.

Comment: This is what i did! I asked if it is correct, indeed

Comment: No you need to derive again. $f(x_o)  = 0$ does not imply $f'(x_o) = 0$

Comment: Ok, that's true. But the exercise tells that $f'(x_{0})=f(x_{0})$ and if i substitute $x'(0)=y'(0)=0$ in the first derivative i computed i get zero. Or maybe i can't get the point...

Comment: A simpler example of your mistake: If $h(z)=z^2$, then $h(0)={dh\over dz}(0)=0$. Does that mean that ${d^2h\over dz^2}(0)=0$? Of course not, since the value of the second derivative is $2$ for *all* values of $z$.

Comment: Thanks, of course you're right and i definitely confused. Hence I computed $g'(t)$ as
$g'(t)=f_{x}(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+f_{y}(x(t),y(t))y'(t)=(6x^2y-y^2+1)x'(t)+(2x^3-2xy+2)y'(t)$
Then i computed $g''$ as:
$g''(t)=f_{x}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+f_{y}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+f_{x x}(dx/dt)^2+2 f_{x y} \frac{dx}{dt} dy/dt+f_{y y}(dy/dt)^2$
By substitution i get $g''(0)=-3$. I hope this process and the computations are correct. Thanks a lot for any suggestion